# How to reset the display of nodes?

Tags: 8, display-suite

For some reason I can no longer manage the display of a node in the backend. Managing the form display works but not the frontend display managing. I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 50 seconds exceeded in
>   /customers/2/f/2/igghq.com/httpd.www/core/modules/field_ui/src/Element/FieldUiTable.php
>   on line 100

I can still manage the display of other content types. Just not that specific one. Is there a way to reset the manage display backend form, maybee through the database?

- running display suite
- Drupal 8

More info: it only locks-up when loading the default display mode. Teaser still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uninstalled and installed fieldgroups and that fixed it. I could access the default display of the content type again. Now I have to redo all my tabs but hey. I now know what killed it. I'll report back if i can find official confirmation of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to post my solution(i encounter it too) if anyone stumble upon.

You don't have to uninstall and reinstall fieldgroup if you know which content type is causing this issue.

- Go to Configuration Export ( [your URL]/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export)
- Choose *Entity View Display* in  **Configuration type**
- Look for your content type in **Configuration Name**
- Copy the configuration that appeared in **Here is your configuration:**
- Open a text file and paste your config.
- Look for *field_group:* , delete it together with it's child or until *id*
- Then re-import your config.

That works for me without resetting other content type field groups.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit your `php.ini` for this. Open it and locate the `max_execution_time` setting. In your case, it will be set to `50`. Update the setting to `300` for example (300 seconds = 5 minutes), save the file and restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, but i don't have access to that file. Also any changes to .htaccess file will brick my site. My hosting doesn't allow that. That is why I'm asking if there is a way to change or reset the dispaly directly through the database.

Answer (score 0):

Another place you can update is settings.php file.

Simply try this `-> edit sites/default/settings.php` and added the following line:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: Again thank but no dice. The max execution time is still 50 s. No aswer to my first question maybee? How can I reset the display? That might fix it. Maybee there is a way to change the active layout. Or i could set all fields to be not visible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Page Manager enabled?

If you're using D7, Page Manger comes with C-tools module.

If you're using D8, you need to [download it](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager).

So enable the Page Manager module, and you should be able to manage them all from here.